# Querying mongoDb documents in Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have this database structure :

- Airport

  - airportId
  - List< Flight > flights
- Aircrafts

  - aircraftId
  - List< Flight > flights
- Flight

  - flightId

I want to get the flights by airportId and aircraftId ( findByAirportAndAircraft ), is it possible ?

Or should I change my database schema ( add airport and aircraft to Flight )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better way is to add the airportId and aircraftId to Flight document (Add only the IDs to keep database simple and consistent and to avoid redundancy) then it will be easy to select flights by airportId and aircraftId:

Add to FlightRepository this method :

```
List<Flight> findByAirportIdAndAircraftId(String airportId, String aircraftId);
```